# HAL Specification - Should self link contain query parameter?

Tags: rest, restful-url, hateoas, hal-json

Following the [HAL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) should the **self** link contain the query parameter or is it ok to link to the first page?
Thanks

Follows an example:

Request:

`my-service/movies/123/subtitles?page=3`

Actual JSON response:

```
{
  "count": 20,
  "pagingSize": 5,
  "_links": {
    "next": {
      "href": "/my-service/movies/123/subtitles?page=4"
    },
    "previous": {
      "href": "/my-service/movies/123/subtitles?page=2"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "/my-service/movies/123/subtitles"
    },
    "movie": {
      "href": "/my-service/movies/123"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/my-service/subtitles/111"
          }
        }
      },
      ...    
      {
        "id": "222",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/my-service/subtitles/222"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hypertext Application Language](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) (HAL) proposed [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-03) specification enforces the "href" in conformity with the "Target IRI" defined in Web Linking specification ([RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)).

> Applications that don't wish to register a relation type can use an
> extension relation type, which is a URI [RFC3986] that **uniquely**
> identifies the relation type.

So I'd say that the self value must be unique, and thus *include any (unspecified optional) query parameters*.